# threeparttable \midrule-sized space

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to add some space between rows of my threeparttable.  One way is to add `\midrule`s, but that adds lines which are visually confusing.  Is there a `\midspace` command?

Side question: Is `threeparttable` the best table to use in `memoir`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package provides `\addlinespace`, which by default adds a space equal to that of `\midrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
letter & number \\
A & 1 \\
B & 2 \\
\midrule
C & 3 \\
\addlinespace% adds \defaultaddspace (by default 5pt)
D & 4 \\
\addlinespace[3pt]
E & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you didn't know: The `booktabs` manual is a must read on *"how to build typographic pleasant tables"* (Sveinung).

Comment: I suggest that to your answer you add a recommendation to `Booktabs`’ excellent documentation on how to build typographic pleasant tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can add vertical space in the optional argument of the `\\` command:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
test \\
test \\[\smallskipamount]
test
\end{tabular}
```

`\smallskipamount`, `\medskipamount` and `\bigskipamount` are predefined lengths that are used by `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip` vertical spacing commands. Of course, you can also specify any other length in the optional argument.

Using (not too big) vertical space to separate parts of a table should be typographically fine. But, IMO, rules should be preferred for caption rows or "total" rows.

Comment: That looks great.  What's the default if I don't specify anything?  (Just to understand.)

Comment: @NeilG: The default is no additional space :-)

Comment: I see: these are additional to the default space.  Thanks :)